# Validation of negative input

Tags: java

I am trying to validate a user input. I don't want the user to enter negative numbers, strings, and doubles number. I only need int. I am only able to validate strings and doubles. Your help will be appreciated.

```
do {

    System.out.println("How many cappuccino drinks were sold today?");
    if(input.hasNextInt()) {

        cappuccinoDrink = input.nextInt();


            capexpenses = cappuccinoDrink * 1.56;
            capRevenue = cappuccinoDrink * 3.50;
            capProfit = capRevenue - capexpenses;
            isNumber = true;

    }else {
        System.out.println("You didn't didn't enter the require imput");
        isNumber = false;
        input.next();
    }
} while(!isNumber);
```

Comment: Try `String.matches("\\d+")` which is a regular expression for one or more digits.

Comment: this is like, I'm only able to calculate 1+2 but how much is 1+1? What I'm trying to say is that you already done it, you should be able to finish it yourself!

Comment: LOL! I am new to java. Sometime I get confused. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `if(input.hasNextInt()) {` to the following:

```
if(input.hasNextInt() && (cappuccinoDrink = input.nextInt()) >= 0) {
            //removed assignment as it is handled in if statement
            capRevenue = cappuccinoDrink * 3.50;
            capProfit = capRevenue - capexpenses;
            isNumber = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int cappuccinoDrink;
boolean invalidinput = true;
System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer : ");
while(invalidInput){
   try{
     cappuccinoDrink = input.nextInt();
     if( cappuccinoDrink<= 0) {  
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer value: ");
     }
     else{invalidInput=false;}
   }
   catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer value: ");
   }
}
        capexpenses = cappuccinoDrink * 1.56;
        capRevenue = cappuccinoDrink * 3.50;
        capProfit = capRevenue - capexpenses;
```